# "invejar" no sentido de "desejar" tem uso no português falado em Portugal?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

> Sei lá quantas vezes desci esse Tejo
>
> E fui pelo mar fora com a alma a sangrar
>
> Levando na ideia uns lábios que **invejo**
>
> E aquela janela virada p´ro mar.

Ouvindo a linda canção de Tristão da Silva, notei o uso de "invejar" no sentido de desejar. Não, não é novidade para mim, mas é muito raro ouvir o verbo usado nesse sentido no Brasil. Dizemos "invejar o sucesso de alguém" mas não invejar os lábios, ou outra parte do corpo. Se tu disseres a alguma mulher: "invejo os teus cabelos", ela certamente entenderá que tu gostarias de ter cabelos iguais ao dela, mas nunca que tens desejo de acariciá-los.

Pergunto: Em ptPT o verbo invejar com o sentido de desejar está restrito à literatura e, como no Brasil não seria entendido se usado coloquialmente?

Comment: Vou te responder aqui por causa do achismo da minha resposta. Em Portugal é usado como explicaste em cima, acho.

Comment: @Jacinto   A versão que tenho é a que foi gravada por Francisco José, e nela a frase inicial é "Sei lá quantas vezes matei o desejo".  Sei que existem outras versões e, provavelmente a original do Tristão é aquela que tu escreveste.

Comment: Faz rollback se quiseres. Eu ouvi o próprio Tristão e [confirmei aqui](http://www.vagalume.com.br/tristao-da-silva/aquela-janela-virada-pro-mar.html). Não fazia ideia que havia duas versões. Nem uma, foi a primeira vez que ouvi a canção. No contexto, "descer o Tejo" faz mais sentido que "matei o desejo". Ele mata o desejo e vai com a alma a sangrar?

Comment: @Jacinto  Fica melhor assim.  Tejo rima com invejo e deve ser a versão original do Tristão.   Eu sabia que existia uma versão diferente mas já estou tão acostumado com aquela cantada por Francisco José que nem fui checar qual a correta,

Comment: Para o que perguntas não é relevante. Fiquei intrigado com a questão da rima, e quis ouvir. (Estava à espera que fosse um cantor brasileiro, e que a rima de "desejo" e "invejo" fosse perfeita no sotaque dele!)

Comment: @Jacinto  Fico surpreso com o fato de uma canção tão bonita não ser conhecida por todos em Portugal.

Comment: O pessoal da minha geração estava mais interessado em pop/rock. A versão do F. José é bem mais produzida. A do Tristão deve ser mesmo a original, está listada como um dos seus êxitos na Wikipédia.

Comment: @Jacinto  Teu comentário: "Ele mata o desejo e vai com a alma a sangrar?"   Provavelmente matou o desejo da forma errada, como um adolescente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foi a primeiríssima vez que eu ouvi ou li o verbo **invejar** ser usado como na canção. E já somos para aí uns três ou quatro portugueses a dizer mesmo, pelo que começamos a ter uma indicação segura que o *invejo* da canção é uma liberdade artística. Os dicionários parecem corroborar esta ideia. Passo a citar o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (DACL) em **invejar**:

> (1) Querer para si o que é de outrem; desejar ter o que outra pessoa tem; ter inveja. = cobiçar. *Invejava-lhe a inteligência. Todos invejavam o seu à-vontade. Invejo esse teu vestido.*
>
> (2) Sentir despeito, desgosto porque alguém tem mais, é melhor ou é mais feliz; ter inveja. *Uma amiga que sempre a invejara tentou prejudicá-la.*

As definições incluem *ter inveja*, mas não vale a pena incluir aqui as definições de *inveja* do DACL, porque não acrescentam nada: as explicações são circulares. Como sugerem os exemplos do DACL, a inveja pode ir do inocente (foste promovido! bestial pá, *também quer ia*, temos que festejar) ao odioso (foi promovido, o cabrão, filho da puta).

Agora a definição (1), com o seu *querer para si o que é de outrem, cobiçar*, pode gerar uma certa confusão. Afinal o cantor parece desejar os lábios que são de outrem, o que de acordo com (1) pode parecer ser *invejar* num sentido literal que nenhum de nós conhecia. A questão é que o significado preciso de *querer, desejar, cobiçar* depende *daquilo* que se deseja, quer, etc.

Quando eu digo que quero os lábios dela, não estou a sugerir irmos os dois ao hospital para transplantar os lábios dela para mim (isto seria inveja). Antes quero dizer que quero beijar os lábios. E quase de certeza não só os lábios: também a cara, o pescoço, e o resto todo; quero-a toda, corpo e alma, para mim. Isto não é invejá-la, nem no sentido (1) nem no (2). Logo, a canção está a recorrer à liberdade artística. Agora se ela já tivesse companheiro, aí eu podia muito bem invejar o filho da mãe.

Comment: +1 for wit.   Jacinto, could it be archaic?

Comment: Never came across it. Not in Eça deQeuiroz, nem no Machado de Assis, nem no Camilo de Castelo Branco (1825-90), Alexandre Herculano (1810-77), nem mesmo no Fernão Mendes Pinto (151?-1583). Só li umas coisitas de cada um, mas parece-me que já daria para ter notado se eles usassem. Cá para mim resulta de liberdade artística agrilhoada pelas exigências da rima e métrica.

Answer (score 7):

A frase soa-me estranha.

De facto, o Aulete dá estas duas definições para *invejar*:

> 1. Ter inveja de (alguém): *invejar os pais, o amigo, o vizinho.*
> 2. Cobiçar (o que é de outrem): *Sempre invejou o trabalho de seu irmão.*

E, de facto, eu posso *cobiçar* os lábios de alguém e sem dúvida que *invejar* o trabalho do meu irmão pode significar que o cobiço (i.e. quero muito o trabalho dele ou um igual).

Mas parece-me que *invejar* tem sempre uma conotação negativa, que há algum resentimento em relação à pessoa na situação que invejamos. O Priberam [concorda comigo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/inveja) -- define invejar apenas como *ter inveja de* ou *olhar com inveja* e *inveja* como:

> 1. Desgosto pelo bem alheio.
> 2. Desejo de possuir o que outro tem (acompanhado de ódio pelo possuidor).

Por isso, eu *invejar os lábios de alguém* pode significar duas coisas:

> 1. Que resinto uma pessoa (ou pelo menos fico desgostado) por ela ter dados lábios (presumivelmente bons lábios).
> 2. *Adicionalmente*, que quero uns lábios como os dessa pessoa.

(Já agora, como curiosidade, *desejo* nem sequer rima com *invejo* em Portugal)

DACL, invejar

> 1 Querer para si o que é de outrem; desejar ter o que outra pessoa tem; ter inveja. = cobiçar. *Invejava-lhe a inteligência. Todos invejavam o seu à-vontade. Invejo esse teu vestido.*
>
> 2 Sentir despeito, desgosto porque alguém tem mais, é melhor ou é mais feliz; ter inveja. *Uma amiga que sempre a invejara tentou prejudicá-la.*

DACL, inveja (1 e 2 são sentimentos correspondentes aos significados acima)

> 3. Tudo aquilo que provoca um desejo de posse, que é objeto de cobiça.

Não dá exemplos, mas imagino que poderia ser *tem uma casa que é a inveja de todos*

Comment: Artefacto realmente nem tinha pensado nisso não rimam nem perto disso.

Comment: Mas Tejo já rima.

Comment: A primeira definição do Aulete "invejar = ter inveja de alguém"  Parece um pensamento cirucular: "invejar é ter inveja de alguém.  E ter inveja de alguém é invejar."  Não define nada.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu pensei em pôr a definição deles para "inveja" (de resto é mais ou menos a mesma que a do Priberam, com mais um ponto que não vem ao caso), mas queria antes focar-me no significado 2.

Comment: Os significados possíveis de _cobiçar_, como de _querer_ dependem do objeto. _Cobiçar/querer lábios_ quer quase de certeza dizer querer beijá-los, e amar, não invejar o dono deles. _Cobiçar/querer o trabalho do irmão_, significa, na melhor das hipóteses, querer um trabalho igual; na pior, ter rancor ao irmão e quere ficar-lhe com o trabalho, ou seja invejá-lo.

Comment: @Jacinto Certo; eu também não muito o que fazer com o "cobiçar" (sem mais) do Aulete, se de facto pode ser usado sem haver de facto inveja. Infelizmente, os meus dicionários de jeito (Houaiss e Academia das Ciências) estão em Lisboa.

Comment: DACL _cobiçar_ Desejar ou querer muito para si o que pertence a outrem ou o que não se tem. A definição do DACL de _invejar_ não permite entender o verso senão em sentido figurado. Se quiseres escrevo-a na tua resposta, e depois tu arruma-la como quiseres

Comment: @Jacinto Se adiantar alguma coisa em relação à definição que eu tenho, agradeceria.